# Characterize cokernel pair in Set

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

In the category of sets (**Set**), can we characterize the [cokernel pair](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cokernel+pair) of a function $f : A\rightarrow B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $s, t:B\rightarrow C$ be the cokernel pair.

$C$ is the coproduct $B + B$, but with the image of $f$ identified (glued together), in other words:

$$C = \mathrm{im} f + (B - \mathrm{im} f) + (B - \mathrm{im} f)$$

The two morphism $s, t$ are simply the left and right coprojections into $C$.

To see why this is, observe that the cokernel pair is defined as the pushout of the function along itself:

$$
  \array{
 &&&&
     A
     &&&&
      \\
      & 
      && f \swarrow
       &
       & \searrow f
      && 
     \\
&& B &&&& B
\\
      & 
      && s\searrow
       &
       & \swarrow t
      && 
     \\
&&&&
     C
     &&&&
  }
$$

We [know](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pushout#pushouts_in_) that in **Set**, $C$ is defined as the set $B + B$ up to the equivalence $b_1 \cong b_2$ iff there exists $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b_1$ and $f(a) = b_2$; in other words, iff $b_1 = b_2 \in \mathrm{im} f$.

This means that $C$ has one copy of $\mathrm{im} f$ and two copies of every other element.

Comment: So you ask a question and immediately answer it? What is the purpose? Either you already know the answer and you don't need the question, or you found the answer just moment after posting your question and you can just delete it. (Or edit it to include the answer in the question).

Comment: I posted a self-answered question to preserve what I figured out for posterity, so that other people who google it can find my answer. Doing so seems to be [encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: I wasn't aware of that rule, but it seems very weird. The SE forums are not an encyclopedia and if everybody does that for every question they encounter and solve, it will be so much more difficult to navigate around the forum and provide/fetch help. (Note that I don't criticize the fact of answering your own question if you come up with a solution later when the question is already posted, that prevents people wasting time on something you figured out on your own.)